# .htaccess file gives 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

I receive 500 internal server error on my website. I think this is because of .htaccess file, but I don't know what's wrong with it.

Server: DirectAdmin, Linux-based

Contents of the .htaccess file is as the following:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_START
<files license.txt>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
<files wp-config-sample.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
<files readme.html>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

#AIOWPS_BLOCK_WP_FILE_ACCESS_END
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 /(.*)/xmlrpc\.php$
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_PINGBACK_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options All -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_START
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_TRACE_TRACK_END
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|='$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
</limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[BAD IPS]
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
# uncomment/edit/repeat next line to block IPs
# Deny from 123.456.789
</limit>
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_START
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-comments-post\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*)?\.spna\.co\.ir [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1 [L]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_BLOCK_SPAMBOTS_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And here's what the Apache Error Log says:

```
[Thu Jan 16 00:19:08 2014] [alert] [client 157.55.35.85] /home/sapna/domains/spna.co.ir/public_html/.htaccess: Option All not allowed here
```

I would be grateful if you help me find out what causes the 500 internal server error.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your Apache's error.log for the reason of 500

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your help. But how should I check this log!? Where is it exactly located? (I'm using DirectAdmin)

Comment: That I won't be able to know since every system has different path for error.log. You may need to contact your server admin for this.

Comment: Thanks again. I found the Apache Error Log which says: "[Thu Jan 16 00:19:08 2014] [alert] [client 157.55.35.85] /home/sapna/domains/spna.co.ir/public_html/.htaccess: Option All not allowed here"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is this line due to your Apache cnfig:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

change this to:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhhava for your answer. This worked for me. But what had caused this problem!? And what shall I do to avoid such problems in the future?

Comment: You'll need `Options All` line in your Apache `httpd.conf` for your site.

Comment: @anubhava Dear, i am using your answer on my script but i get Internal Server Error in one domain. Can you please check my question for me, please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744800/mod-rewrite-enabled-but-i-get-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 34):

Often **500 Internal Server Error** happens if you fail to load the mod_rewrite module.

To enable **RewriteEngine On** you need to run the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I had the same issue with Docker and adding `RUN a2enmod rewrite` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you. Had this issue in the docker. And your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Man, you saved me!

Answer (score 10):

### In Local mechine

1. Create your project folder.
2. Create .htaccess file in your project root directory like below.

### .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

3. Save .htaccess file.
4. Now click on wamp / lamp / xamp server icon and click on apache and select "rewire_module".

### In Cpanel

1. Directly you need to create .htaccess file with above code and save.

Note: - Please don't write any spelling mistakes in cpanel. If you write any spelling mistakes it will gives you an internal server error (500).

Answer (score 8):

I was facing same problem, here is solution for **ubuntu and apache**
 It was because **mod_rewrite module was not enabled**, First enable module rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now edit for directory level

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

add these lines at end

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

and restart apache again.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Great, that solved my problem. The module was not enabled

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem too, I was missing the a2enmod rewrite activation in the first place and after activating it, it solved my problem right away.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **AllowOverride Options privileges** to use **Options**