# mod_rewrite enabled but i get 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

I get an 500 Internal Server Error when i use my htaccess code from another server. Just i get this error in a new server. I talked with my hosting provider but they said mod_rewrite enabled. It will be come from your htaccess code. Can anyone can help me where i am doing wrong in my htaccess code:

```
# HTTPS redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 https://website.nl/not-found.php          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^status/([\w-]+)/?$ status.php?msgID=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([\w-]+)/?$ admin/index.php?set=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]  
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved|stories)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]  
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please check your server error log file that will tell you what caused the 500 error.

Comment: @starkeen The error_log file said: `/sites/website.nl/www/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here, referer: https://flungo.nl/  
/sites/website.nl/www/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here `

Comment: Then, remove that line from your htaccess.

Comment: @anubhava Yes they said me that enabling it in htaccess wasnt neccesary for the cms to work on their host. I don't understand what that answer means.

Comment: ok in that case comment out `Options` line and retry

Comment: @anubhava I have tryed before the page is showing this page have too many redirection. But when i remove .htaccess the page is working normaly.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: @anubhava It says 302

Comment: Provide full details. If you're getting too many redirections when dev tool should show multiple URLs with status codes. What are those URLs and what are status codes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192073/discussion-between-azzo-and-anubhava).